# ¿Como configurar un Combobox para mejor vista?

Tags: c#

Les comento, tengo 2 `Combobox` que se despliegan de la misma forma que muestro en la captura de pantalla, he visto en sus propiedades pero no encuentro una opción para que por ejemplo se haga mas pequeña la lista(que muestra 10 y con la barra pueda ver los demas) y que se visualice del `Combobox` hacia abajo y no de esa manera fea.

Se que es algo visual pero me gustaría que se viera de la mejor forma. Espero puedan apoyarme. De antemano Muchas Gracias.

[image: ComboBox raro]

Comment: talvez el control que necesitas no sea un combobox

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero no dijiste nada. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con estas propiedades

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
```

Prueba con esa configuración, si tu lista no despliega como quieres, añade tambien la siguiente propiedad

```
comboBox.IntegralHeight = false;
```

La primer línea de código es la manera en la que tu `combobox` mostrara los datos, en este caso, hacia abajo del control.
La segunda línea es el número máximo de items a mostrar.
La última línea esta siempre en `true` y lo que hace es ajustar el tamaño del `combobox` de manera manual basado en el espacio disponible en el form.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por apoyarme en algo tan sencillo y básico.